# Complicated integration with $\arcsin$ problem

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> $\int_{1}^{-1}\sqrt {8-3x^2}dx$

I was instructed to use substitution $x=\sqrt{\frac{8}{3}}\sin v$ but I think I mess something cause I get $\cos (\arcsin x)$ and don't now what to do with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle\arcsin x=\phi\implies\sin\phi=x$ and $-\frac\pi2\le \phi\le\frac\pi2$ based the [principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) value of inverse sine ratio

So, $\displaystyle\cos(\arcsin x)=\cos\phi=+\sqrt{1-\sin^2\phi}=+\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Answer (score 2):

$\arcsin x$ is the angle whose sine is *x*. And since $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$, how much is the cosine then ? :-)

Comment: what about the sign?

Comment: Given the symmetry of the integrand, we can write that $\int_1^{-1}=2\int_1^0$, in which case our angle is in between $\arcsin0=0$ and $\arcsin1=90$ degrees, and the sign is positive.

Comment: don't you think this deliberation can safely demand an entry in the answer, itself?

Comment: No. It wasn't sign details that perplexed our inquirer. Why ?